# What exactly happened with Apple throttling iPhones?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, performance

I'm doing a business report on Apple Inc. and I'm on the legal issues section and I have to list and describe a few recent (last ~5-10 yrs) issues/lawsuits that the company faced. So far a major one appears to be them throttling old iPhones, and from what I've searched it seems that this was caused by an iOS update of some sort that slowed phones, preventing them from abruptly shutting off. So people thought their phones were defunct and bought new ones, while they didn't know they simply could've replaced the battery. Thus, lawsuits were filed. Am I right on this?

Any correction/clarification would be appreciated. Providing any other major lawsuits/cases against Apple would also be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You've mostly got - only thing I'd adjust is that the lawsuits mostly revolve around them not notifying customers of these changes. These days, of course, it's documented and explained. But originally it wasn't even in release notes. The throttling is defensible of course, since it prevented the phones from crashing – but since they didn't tell people, they did experience lawsuits.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about solving a practical problem related to using Apple products as described in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some say throttling.

Others say the system stays running until you can have the battery serviced.

You are right. Lots of opinions and people taking action without learning the physics and basics. If Apple had been more open what was happening sooner, the lawsuit might not have succeeded to reach class-action status, but laws can be horribly flawed (slavery, death sentences, chopping off fingers or hands for instance). In the US pretty much anyone can sue and sometimes settling is smart to avoid risk of an adverse finding and not an admission or merit or guilt.